# jQuery: Pass anchor element to function when clicked

Tags: jquery

So.. This one should be simple.  I have an anchor element.  When it is clicked, I want to call a function that will delete it's parent element.  Essentially, it is a link to remove the parent.

How would I accomplish this?  I have tried using the following, which is not working:

```
<div>
     <a href='javascript:removeParent()'>Remove</a>
</div>
<script>
function removeParent() {
     $( this ).parent().remove()
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out?

I'm trying to accomplish this because it is a form that can have multiple attributes... So you can add more attributes and thus need a way to remove them.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(this) isn't the element the way you're doing it.

Ideally, this:

```
<a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>

$('.remove').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

However this part of your question "**So you can add more attributes and thus need a way to remove them.**" means you need to apply this to future elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Though in an ideal situation you'd give jQuery less to search, so give your list wrapper an ID and use that to identify the removable elements.

```
$('#attributelist').on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: @somekindarukus - using a class-based event handler like this is much better than your inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the elements dynamically after onload, you'll need to modify popnoodle's code to use a container:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {...
```

This assumes that all the elements with the class `remove` are in the element `container`. It creates one event handler on `container` that will apply to any elements of the class `remove`, even if they are created after the handler is attached.